# WooCommerce hook to add custom order columns

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce hook that adds a custom column in WooCommerce->Orders page.

The hook is called: `manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column`

Now, I've added two custom columns. One of them contains a drop-down that fetches the value from DB and show as selected. What I want to do is to allow the user to change the status using the dropdown form, and I've placed a submit button there as well.

However, I'm facing a very strange problem. That is, the form is only being posted for the 1st order (1st row) and for the other orders, the submit button doesn't post any data and due to which I can't run my update query on this button click. I'm also sharing the code snippet below:

```
case 'my-column2':
    $sql    = "SELECT payment_status FROM custom_payments_data WHERE order_id = " . $post_id;
    $result = $dbConnection->query( $sql );
    
    if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            $status = $row["payment_status"];
        }
        ?>
        <!-- Building Payment Status form in WooCommerce Admin Orders -->
        <form action = "<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ). 'order_update.php';?>" method ="POST">
            <select style= "width: 100%;" id = "status" name = "status" class = "no-link">
                <option value = "Waiting Confirmation" <?php if($status == "Waiting Confirmation") echo 'selected = "selected"' ?>> Waiting Confirmation</option>
                <option value = "Pending Payment" <?php if($status == "Pending Payment") echo 'selected="selected"' ?>> Pending Payment</option>
                <option value = "Confirmed" <?php if($status == "Confirmed") echo 'selected="selected"' ?>> Confirmed</option>
            </select>
            <input type = "submit" class = "MyURLsubmit no-link"  name ="submit" id="MyURLsubmit" value = "Change Status">
        </form>
        <?php
        //} //End of while
    } // End of IF statement FORM
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't rebuild your problem since a lot of your code is missing (like the code where you add the column). Please improve your answer if you expect a professional question.

Comment: Apologies for not sharing the full code because I didn't want to make it too lengthy for people to read. Here's the full code:
http://collabedit.com/apt2a

Comment: You are just adding a custom column with some content. Where is the part where you save everything? It's missing in your code.

Comment: The code was there before and I've added it again. I'm trying trying to access the form fields by $_POST variable after the switch statement is ended.

Comment: In this case you can use the admin_init hook to check if the POST variable is set. YOu can do your saving there.

Comment: So you mean after this hook ends, I should use the admin_init hook and use these POST variables there? Thank you for being helpful.

Comment: Yes! Try accessing the POST variable in this hook and save the content wherever you want.